# Angular 6: Strange "Property xxx is protected and only accessible within class and its subclasses

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I have a library project that I'm migrating to Angular 6 and Angular CLI 6.

There's an abstract class called `NativeFormElementChild` that has some private properties: `_id`, `_required`, `_ariaDescribedBy`, and `_ariaRequired`.

Then I have a directive, `InputDirective`, that's applied to a `<input>` as an attribute (adds some extra functionality). `InputDirective` extends from `NativeFormElementChild`.

Now when I try to build this in Angular 6, I get errors galore. Everywhere I use my `InputDirective`, I get four errors:

- Property '_id' is protected and only accessible within class 'NativeFormElementChild' and its subclasses.
- Property '_required' is protected and only accessible within class 'NativeFormElementChild' and its subclasses.
- Property '_ariaDescribedBy' is protected and only accessible within class 'NativeFormElementChild' and its subclasses.
- Property '_ariaRequired' is protected and only accessible within class 'NativeFormElementChild' and its subclasses.

I'm not trying to access these properties from anywhere except inside `NativeFormElementChild`. So I have no idea where these errors are coming from. Using Angular 5, I don't get any of these errors.

Comment: are you perhaps referencing those variable somewhere in the template? if you build in production mode in angular 5, do you get any error?

Comment: @Ringo production mode/AOT build on Angular 5 succeeds.

Comment: hmm, sounds like a bug with linter/codelyzer. Changing it from private to public will be a temporary get around?

Comment: I've discovered that protected properties only work on *ngFor loop elements in Angular 6.  If I try to use them outside of a loop I get the error when doing a production build.

Comment: Please provide some code demonstrating a minimal test case that would help others to reproduce the problem. See [mcve] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your component html, place a `*ngIf="true"` in the outer most html tag.  That seems to activate Angular 6's understanding of protected properties.  Any `*ng` tag (Template Binding) will work.  You'll need one for each component html.

```
<div *ngIf="true">
...Everything in here will now properly have access to protected properties
</div>
```

or if you don't have an outer element you can use an `ng-container`...

```
<ng-container *ngIf="true">
...
</ng-container>
```

Comment: How will this help with the compile-time errors the OP is getting? They don't say they're getting the error in HTML or JSX...

Comment: He's getting a build error when applying his `InputDirective` to `<input>` tags.  Those errors are generated by Angular compiling template bindings connecting to html pages.